# Python maximum recursion depth exceeded in flask app

Tags: python, flask

Here is the error:

```
maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I'm using `beautifulsoup` to parse a web page HTML that I received from `requests` and then I'm storing the parsed data into `Product` class. the function ran by calling a thread from `ThreadPoolExecutor()`.

running the function:

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
t2 = executor.submit(ScrapePageFull, PageHtml)
product = t2.result()
```

`ScrapePageFull` function:

```
def ScrapePageFull(data):
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
product = Product()

# Price
price = soup.find(DIV, {ID: DATA_METRICS})[ASIN_PRICE]
product.price = float(price)

# ASIN
ASIN = soup.find(DIV, {ID: DATA_METRICS})[ASIN_ASIN]
product.asin = ASIN

# Title
title = soup.find(META, {NAME: TITLE})[CONTENT]
product.title = title

# Price String
price_string = soup.find(SPAN, {ID: PRICE_BLOCK}).text
product.price_string = price_string

return product
```

and here is the `Product` class:

```
class Product:
def __init__(self):
    self.title = None
    self.price = None
    self.price_string = None
    self.asin = None
    pass

# Getters
@property
def title(self):
    return self.title

@property
def price(self):
    return self.price

@property
def asin(self):
    return self.asin

@property
def price_string(self):
    return self.price_string

# Setters
@title.setter
def title(self, title):
    self.title = title

@price.setter
def price(self, price):
    self.price = price

@asin.setter
def asin(self, asin):
    self.asin = asin

@price_string.setter
def price_string(self, price_string):
    self.price_string = price_string
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're entering infinite recursion here:

```
@property
def title(self):
    return self.title
```

Returning `self.title` is the same as calling this function again because defining a function called `title` overwrites the variable `self.title`.

This is infinite recursion as well:

```
@title.setter
def title(self, title):
    self.title = title
```

`@title.setter` will redefine assignment like `self.title = title` to call `self.title.setter(title)` from within this function.

Same thing for `self.price`, `self.price_string` and `self.asin`.

To solve this, rename your variables:

```
def __init__(...):
   self._title = None

@property
def title(self):
    return self._title
```

Comment: Good explanation. Of course in this case it would be even better to drop the usage of `@property` and to access the attributes.